# What does each graph cuadrant means with LDA vis plot from R?

Tags: graph-theory, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I am speeking about [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IksL96ls4o0) graph, that shows a big probability mass. [image: LDAvis] This is the way that it finally shows with some data I found online and used to understand Latent Dirichlet Allocation topic modeling. As far as I understand, this graphic is ideal to give out final names to each topic according to the frequency or relevance of each term given the topic but I've got two questions: **1. What would you simply say about topic 8 position on the graph?** Meaning that I can't tell what each square represent in this graph, I can't tell in plain words what's the difference between topic 1 and 10, or topic 8 and 3, given their position on this graph. **2. What can you tell about the big gray line in comparisson to the red filling when lambda is 0?** I mean, I think I get that when lambda is 1, it's meaning about plain frequency of the term in the whole corpus vs the frequency of the terms in that topic, but I'm not sure I get it with putting more wight in the ratio from red to gray, what is the gray line saying about that term and how is red contransting?

Comment: Question 1 is difficult to answer, as the screenshot you included has not topic 8 selected (the numeric field in the upper left). I pass on Question 2, since I do not the meaning of lambda in this case.